# CodeFixProvider-derived class: how to properly format code that is moved in a new block?

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, code-formatting, roslyn

I'm using [visual-studio-2015](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015) and trying to figure out [roslyn](/questions/tagged/roslyn) code analysis services. In my learning process I want to create an analyzer that will cause a warning to appear when `using` statements are placed at the top of a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) code file, rather than within a namespace declaration. I also want the IDE to provide me with a quick shortcut to allow easy fixing of the faulting code.

For example, whenever the code analysis tool sees this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class TypeName
    {   
    }
}
```

... I want it to show a warning and propose to turn it into this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    class TypeName
    {   
    }
}
```

I managed to get my analyzer class (derived from `DiagnosticAnalyzer`) working like I want. **My main issue right now is with the `CodeFixProvider`-derived class**.

Technically, right now, it works; the statements *are* moved down to namespace declarations. However, The formatting is not so good. Here is what I actually get when trying to fix the first code block above:

```
*
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    class TypeName
    {   
    }
}
```

The asterisk character represents a remaining carriage return. Also note how there's a linebreak right after the first namespace bracket and none between using statements and class declaration. I want that linebreak moved down and sit on top of the class.

Here is (parts of interest within) my `CodeFixProvider`-derived class code:

```
public sealed override async Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
{
    foreach (var diagnostic in context.Diagnostics)
    {
        context.RegisterCodeFix(
            CodeAction.Create(
                title: Title,
                createChangedDocument: c => ProvideDocumentAsync(context.Document, c),
                equivalenceKey: Title),
            diagnostic);
    }
}

private async Task<Document> ProvideDocumentAsync(Document document, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false) as CompilationUnitSyntax;

    if (root == null) return null;

    var newRootUsings = new SyntaxList<UsingDirectiveSyntax>();
    var newRoot = root.WithUsings(newRootUsings);

    foreach (var namespaceDecl in newRoot.Members.OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>())
    {
        NamespaceDeclarationSyntax newNsDecl = namespaceDecl;

        foreach (var statement in root.Usings)
        {
            var newStatement = statement.WithLeadingTrivia(statement.GetLeadingTrivia().Union(new[] { Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory.Whitespace("    ") }));

            newNsDecl = newNsDecl.AddUsings(newStatement);
        }

        newRoot = newRoot.ReplaceNode(namespaceDecl, newNsDecl);
    }

    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
}
```

As you can see I did figure out how to add the extra indentation (with `GetLeadingTrivia` method). I suppose I can do the same for extra lines but somehow I feel there's probably a better way I'm not aware of yet, being pretty green with these new code analysis / refactoring tools.

So any guidance on how to make the formatting - or anything else for that matter - any better?

**UPDATE:**

It just occured to me today that the "right" formatting to apply within a Roslyn code fix provider should be the one applied by the code editor by default (in my case, Visual Studio 2015), with its own set of rules.

My understanding is that the `Formatter` class inside the compiler engine can allow "hinting" the code editor that formatting is required on some nodes / textspans. A code fix trying to format the code further than this is probably doing too much.

If anyone believes I'm mistaken, you are very much welcome to chime in. I'm still on training wheels with Roslyn and willing to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Add `.WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation)` to tell Roslyn to auto-format your change.

Comment: @Crono: Any ancestor containing all of the nodes you want to format.

Comment: So that would have to be the root element, since I want to get rid of the top remaining linebreak. But how will this affect the unchanged nodes? For example, if I have a method declared inside the `TypeName` class, will it be reformatted along?

Comment: I added newRoot = newRoot.(your code) right before the `return` statement. It doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Crono: I don't know.

Comment: Tested again, this time in an actual IDE environment (used unit test project before). It does work but as I feared it also attempts on reformatting the complete document. :(

Comment: @Crono: Yes; this is handled by the Roslyn code that invokes the formatter.  You should apply it to only the nodes you want to format.

Comment: `Formatter.Annotation` probably is part of the solution, but IMHO there's still something missing. I don't think it's right for a code fix to reformat the complete document, it should only care about the statement it moves and to a certain extend the first namespace's leading trivia, as well as the spacing around newly moved using statements.

Comment: @Crono: No; you should only add it to the nodes you're actually changing; not the document root.

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, since I'm moving `Using` statements from the root to every child nodes of `NamespaceDeclaration` kind, these are the ones I should want to reformat. The problem is that these nodes have a lot of other descendant nodes on which I do *not* want the formatting to act at this point. Then I tought maybe you meant formatting only the `UsingDirective` nodes. So I tried, but it didn't work. The empty line at the top of the file remained there and a new line was also present between the namespace opening bracket and the newly moved using directives.

Comment: If I just keep getting you wrong, perhaps the best would be that you look at my code and tell me which specific nodes I should add the format annotation on to get the result I want.

Comment: Ah, you're right; I didn't look closely at what nodes you're using.  I'm not sure if there is a better option.

Comment: You could try the `Formatter.FormatAsync` method that takes in a span. Use the start span of the first using directive and the end span of the last one and see if that gets the job done.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Thanks for the input. I just tried `Formatter.FormatAsync`. It works on indentation, but it doesn't remove blank lines. :s

Comment: It just occured to me that the `Formatter` class probably uses formatting rules defined in Visual Studio. In it, there's no way to specify that leading / trailing blank lines should be removed / inserted. Therefore, there's probably no "clean" way to have the code formatted as I want. Even if I did insert / remove trivias in corresponding nodes, that may not be what another developer would expect. So it's probably better not to go further than what `Formatter` class produces.